# URL is not linked properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, broken-link

From [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7378/64282) on Wordpress SE, you can see that the URL is not linked properly:

[image: image description]

But when I click edit, there is nothing wrong with it:

[image: image description]

Comment: but what happens to the link?

Comment: For me it's not linked at all on the main page view, just shows as plain text. When editing it, the *preview* section shows the link correctly, so it's something in the normal page view rendering. (Side note: *blue* freehand circles? That's just radical!)

Comment: @James what's wrong (or right) with blue? I don't get what you mean

Comment: Actually, another answer further down shows the link fine: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/6889/66022 (Nothing with blue circles - everyone uses red - was just joking :) )

Comment: @James ahh, I see :D. I use the Snipping Tool of Windows, and the default color is blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just a rendering bug that existed at the time the answer was created and was still being displayed because posts get permanently cached until they're updated again. Something messed it up, but it's since been corrected. Just needed to be saved over again.

Comment: I see that you only add one period. Why did the bug appear?

Comment: *"because posts get permanently cached until they're updated again"* - So it was broken in 2011 when it was saved. Saving over it causes it to get re-cached using the *current* Markdown parser, which has this issue fixed.